Ответ с кодом, но с фразой (комплимент) на английском
в данном ответе фраза не на том языке только комплимент сайту-"что то вроде хороший сайт у вас(?)", но есть код, который отвечает (?) на вопрос
Получается, что мы удалим ответ ДАЖЕ, если там есть ответ, и фраза на "другом" языке, не имеет отношения к вопросу...

но при попытке рекомендовать удаление, что мне выбрать, если нет "причин" => там не на русском...

как пользователь должен понять "за что" удалили его ответ? в списке причин не должно быть?
*также можно было сделать "дубликат ответа", но такой причины тоже нету. Но ведь это точно не "спам или оскорбительный материал(?)"

А разве там нет кнопки "Править"?

@АлексейШиманский, надо было? Да, вы правы причём с двух сторон, потому что 1. Фраза бесполезная 2. Она не русском, я могла бы просто удалить фразу тем более, тем более, что когда я встречаю на русском "такого рода" фразы, я их удаляю. Круто, что подметили, я весь вечер прокручиваю этот момент в голове.

... И почему мне такие аудиты попадаются‍️сегодня был ответ на тайском....на тайскооомтеперь все иностранные языки мне в аудит

На ответе стоят 4 тревога спама. Но интересно не это, а то, что он по сути копирует код 12-летней давности из принятого ответа - разница в одном названии и в паре имён переменных. Наверное, он не спам, но ценности не представляет и удалён заслуженно.
Вопросы для аудита выбираются автоматически, так что туда вполне могут попадать неудачные варианты. Мне кажется, это один из них. Но если не ошибаюсь, нажатие "править" тоже является успешным прохождением аудита?




Да, так и есть, и в своём вопросе я указала, что это дубликат. Но дело не в том, чтоб я смогла или нет пройти аудит, а в том, что это ведь не спам, или оскорбительный материал. Тут как бы причина в том, что для удаления такого сообщения, нет причины в списке... И да, если отвечать на ваш вопрос, аудит проходится при любом раскладе, кроме "выглядит нормально", а он явно таковым не является.

И мне почти всегда "неудачные" варианты аудита попадают. Вчера попалась "правка", где пишут "мама моя"...

Я тоже подумала, что удалила его заслуженно, потому что там копипаста, но вчера когда Алексей ответил, я вспомнила фразу, что "плохие" ответы тоже ответы, но потом стала думать это же не плохой, а скопированный... Вообщем, если вернуться к прохождению аудита это ок, но если к самой ситуации, она на мой взгляд не однозначна...

Наверно можно добавить среди причин это ответ дубликат???//но мы тут этого сделать не сможем.... И всех с такими вопросами отправляют на англ мету

Главное однажды я так и сделала, когда вопрос был на "другом" языке, что спам или оскорбительный материал, а мне вернули - отклонена ваша тревога... Вообщем, порой все сходится к тому, что трогай все осторожно, везде раскаленные камни... Тревоги не ставь, тревоги ставь...

"Проверки" для "моего" аудита, выбирает Человек, это не рандомное)))только иностранные языки везде https://i.sstatic.net/82lqXOWT.png

Скорее всего это как-раз таки спам и есть. Обратите внимание на измененный адрес в ссылке.
